# How Fix Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 52."

Tags: ios, swift

How to Convert this one. "{\n    ID = \"d9a7c7bf-781d-47b3-bb4e-e1022ec4ce1b\";\n    Name = Headquarters;\n}";  To this format {
                "ID": "d9a7c7bf-781d-47b3-bb4e-e1022ec4ce1b",
                "Name": "Headquarters"
            }

```
 if let jsonString = text as? String {
        let objectData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: objectData!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any] //try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: objectData!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
            print(String(describing: json))
            return json
        } catch {
            // Handle error
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

> Blockquote

Comment: How did you get that `String` (`text`)? It seems to be the description of a `NSDictionary`, not a JSON Dictionary.

Comment: This is not correct json. fix the json structure from the backend

Comment: you have incorrect json string, and want to make correct json string? It is not a problem of JSONSerialization. You should get correct json string like this: `"{\"ID\": \"d9a7c7bf-781d-47b3-bb4e-e1022ec4ce1b\",\"Name\": \"Headquarters\"}"`

Comment: Use json formatter sites to check your json strings : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: What are you using to get that json in the first place, can you maybe give the code to your API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all and already mentioned the string format is clearly **not** JSON.

It's the string format which is returned when calling the `description` property of a Foundation collection type (`NSArray` / `NSDictionary`).
For example a `print` statement calls `description` and this format appears also in output of Terminal.app.

However there is a solution: This string format is called [`openStep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization/propertylistformat/openstep) (an `OpenStep / NeXt` legacy format) and is available in `PropertyListSerialization`

This code reads the format:

```
let string = "{\n ID = \"d9a7c7bf-781d-47b3-bb4e-e1022ec4ce1b\";\n Name = Headquarters;\n}"
let data = Data(string.utf8)

do {
    let dictionary = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil)
    print(dictionary)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Note:

I'm pretty sure that the original data format is **not** openStep and somewhere **you** created the string unnecessarily with the `String(describing` initializer like in the question.

Comment: @vadian: While It's quite happy to know that the PropertyListSerialization can do it back (definitely need to keep that in mind), could it be more interesting to know why the user has in the first place the description of a `NSDictionary`? I think there is code to clean on his/her part and some misunderstanding.

Comment: @Larme I added a note.

Comment: @vadian: i am facing  one more issue like this one : "(\n        {\n        Caption = \"<null>\";\n        ID = 0;\n        IMGURL = \"https://chiefpoint.blob.core.windows.net/publiccommoncdn/Chief-No-Photo1-1024.jpg\";\n    }\n)"; is not convert to NSArray??.  have i can solved this one please guide me!

Comment: Once again I suspect that you are doing the wrong thing. Please edit the question and add the code how you receive the data and how you **get** this string from. It's most unlikely that the server sends this text format as the format is heavily related to macOS.

Answer (score 1):

your json format is incorrect. If you try it with `jsonformatter`  it will throw this error:

[image: error]

so first you need to replace `;` with `,`. The second is that Strings should be wrapped in double quotes, replace `Name = Headquarters` with `Name = "Headquarters"`.

This is the right form

```
{\n ID = \"d9a7c7bf-781d-47b3-bb4e-e1022ec4ce1b\",
\n Name = "Headquarters"\n}
```

Comment: How can i Replace? Could you please explain or give me some example code for that

Comment: i am getting this one from data base : "{\n    ID = \"d9a7c7bf-781d-47b3-bb4e-e1022ec4ce1b\";\n    Name = Headquarters;\n}";  . How can i convert this one?

Comment: then the backend person must format the json for you